# Selected line's contents aren't readable in GEdit while using dark theme on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, themes, gedit

I am unable to see what I type in the Gedit editor using dark theme.

[image: Gedit problem showcase]

This is due to the default setting of highlighting the current line.

[image: Gedit highlight current line setting]

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1857191) for 20.04. You can draw more attention to this bug by checking the relevant option on the top of the bug report to let the developers know that it also affects you.

Comment: My experience is that this only persistantly happens (and color theme change in preferences has not effect) is when using gedit in sudo or su. That's my question. That's what I'm wondering. I'm guessing it's been added as a percaution that you may be overwriting something core - but I would much like to turn it off. and no, Gksu does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36):

Here's my workaround.

Go to the **Preferences** menu on Gedit and change the Color Scheme on **Fonts & Colors** tab:

[image: Color Scheme on Preferences menu]

Check if the text is now comfortably readable even with the presence of the highlighted content on the selected line.

[image: Readable highlighted text]

Comment: Wow, thank you. The default 'dark mode' preference is unusable, in my opinion - I ended up selecting Solarized dark, but there's another dark mode for geddit that's perfectly usable. In my opinion the fix would be to remove the unusable theme.

Answer (score 14):

As you can see in the images, by default the *Higlight current line* feature is enabled in Gedit editor on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal).

Due to that, you can't see what you type in the current line properly, since the font color and highlight color are almost the same.

You can disable *Highlight current line* in the preferences of Gedit or change the color of the text in *Font & Colors* settings.

Comment: Works. Would be fine if by default changing the theme Ubuntu make that automaticly.

Answer (score 11):

You have two options:

1. Open the theme file `/usr/share/gtksourceview-4/styles/tango.xml` with root access and around the line 50 there should be something like this :

```xml
   <color name="aluminium1"                  value="#eeeeec"/>
```

Change the color to something less harsh like `#99999c`.

2. Use another theme.The default theme when the global appearance is set to dark is **tango** but you can also use **Classic** or **Oblivion** depending on your mood and your preferences.None of them have the problem of unreadable text when a line is highlighted.Just go to **Preferences** -> **Font and colors** and change that.

Also you can take a look at [this theme repository](https://github.com/ricardograca/gedit-themes) to find more themes if you want.

Comment: Instead of changing the color, consider changing the `<style name="current-line" ...>` to something other than "aluminium1".